# First check value before we put it into an if statement (CLOSED)

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, equals, isset

I have a form with the following select inputs:

In the first file:

```
<select class="form-control" name="city" id="city">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="breda">Breda</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="interior" id="interior">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="gestoffeerd">Gestoffeerd</option>
</select>
```

In the second file I retrieve that data

```
$search_city = $_POST['city'];
$search_interior = $_POST['interior'];
```

I also have a variable: $result this is an array that I retrieved from an api. In this array are some houses. Each house has some specs as a city and an interior spec.

I want all houses based on what I select in the select form.

When i for example selected a city but not an interior then I will retrieve all houses form that city

When i for example selected an interior but not a city then I will retrieve all houses with that interior from all city's

When i for example nothing selected then I will retrieve all houses

```
if(isset($search_city) == $result['city'] && isset($search_interior) == $result['interior']){
    // echo all results based on selected values
}
```

Comment: Where is $result['interior'] being defined?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2):

In your form, you can change the HTML of the dropdown's first option to be empty:

```
    <select class="form-control" name="city" id="city">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <option value="breda">Breda</option>
    </select>

    <select class="form-control" name="interior" id="interior">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <option value="gestoffeerd">Gestoffeerd</option>
    </select>
```

Then in your PHP logic, you would check if it's empty:

```
if ( !empty( ucfirst($_POST['city'] ) ){
    $city = ucfirst($_POST['city'];
}

if ( !empty( ucfirst($_POST['interior'] ) ){
    $city = ucfirst($_POST['interior'];
}
```

Comment: In this way, you're reducing the complexity of your checks against the posted variables.

Comment: Thanks, but now I still don't get the right city's. If $city not isset then I will get all the city's and not a specific one

Comment: Can you update your question to display the code you're using to actually fetch the data? Might make it a little easier to understand what exactly you're trying to do and having issues with.

Comment: I updated my question hope you will understand me more